# Access colnames of sequentially named data frames

Tags: r

I have a series of sequentially named data frames, i.e "frame_1" "frame_2" frame_3" e.t.c... and I would like to make the first row of each of these frames the colnames using a loop or something similar, so far I have tried:

```
for( i in 1:length(holder)){
  colnames( noquote(paste("frame_",i,sep="")))<- (noquote(paste("frame_",i,sep="")))[1,]
}
```

However this is giving me error

```
Error in unclass(x)[...] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Which I cannot understand, as it should be passing the colnames function "frame_1" "frame_2" e.t.c

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend keeping all data frames in a list instead of multiple objects. Here's an approach:

```
# get the names of the data frames
frame_names <- ls(pattern = "^frame_\\d+$")

# put all data frames in a list
frames <- mget(frame_names)

# change the column names of all data frames in the list
frames <- lapply(frames, function(x) setNames(x, x[1, ]))
```

Afterwards, you can access the data frames in the list `frames`. For example, `frames[[1]]` returns the first data frame (`frame_1`).

Comment: Hi Sven, do you know any good resources for learning this approach? Particularly your third line of code.

Comment: @user1987097 You can have a look at the help page `?lapply`. The function `lapply` allows you to apply a function to all elements in a list. In this example, the list elements are data frames. In the function, the parameter `x` represents the data frame. The function `setNames` changes the column names of the data frame (`x`) to the values in the first row (`x[1, ]`).

Comment: So I could earlier define my own written function, that might for instance delete the first row (or any assignment task) of the argument passed to it, and then using the form you have in your answer apply it to the list of data frames?

Comment: @user1987097 Yes, you can define your own function.